# What is a 'Jack' (as in Jack, Queen, King') ? When was it so designated?

Tags: word-usage, historical-change

In Charles Dicken's *Great Expectations*, published in 1861, when Pip, the hero, plays cards with his friend Estella, the narrative states :

> “He calls the knaves Jacks, this boy!” said Estella with disdain, before our first game was out. “And what coarse hands he has! And what thick boots!”

So what does a 'Jack' represent and was this the first time that it had been so described in English literature ?

Comment: The cited reference is a "social class snub" - just as they tend to say ***couch*** rather than ***sofa***, lower-class commoners usually call that card a ***Jack*** rather than (upper middle-class) ***knave***. It's been like that for *centuries* (Estella is a ***snob***).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OED has

> **24.** *Cards.* Originally in the game of **all fours**: (a name for) the lowest court card of the suit which is trumps, which earns the player who takes it a point; now *rare.* Later *gen.* (originally *colloquial*): the lowest court card of any suit in a pack of cards, ranking below the queen and above the ten, and bearing a representation of a soldier or a pageboy; = **knave**
>
> In the later more general sense, superseding *knave* as the usual term from the late 19th cent. Acceptance of *Jack* as standard was possibly driven by the introduction of corner index letters and numbers on playing cards in the late 19th cent., *J* thus being distinct from *K* (for King).

The earliest citation OED has for *Jack* is from Charles Cotton's *The Compleat Gamester* of 1674:

> This game...is called *All-fours* from Highest, Lowest, Jack, and Game, which is the Set as some play it.
> He that wins Jack wins one [point] also.

OED's conjecture about the "late nineteenth century" is given the lie by one of its own citations, although the importation of an Americanism might be what caused Estella's disdain.

> 1830   *Adams Sentinel* (Gettysburg, Pa.) 22 June 2/2   I'll bet any man ten dollars I can cut the Jack of hearts at the first attempt.

Comment: But a sharp would employ low slang to try to gull the well-to-do out of a sawbuck. That was a lot of cash back then.  The use might be a conscious attempt to present hisself as a chawbacon. I'd like to see a more ordinary use circumstance.

Comment: @PhilSweet There are at least two words in your comment I've never met before.

Comment: Either I mispelt something, or they are from the mid 1800's. I was trying to get in character.

Comment: When I lived in Devil's Lake, the little local library was an old house, and they hadn't acquired any new books in a hundred years ;)